# input a figure between title and body in twocolumn latex form

Tags: latex

I'm using a Latex to write a small paper using CVPR template.

I'd like to put a figure between my title+name and body(which consists with two columns) like many CVPR papers do, but I don't find the way to do that.

I tried,

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{2in} \rule{.9\linewidth}{0pt}}
\end{center}
   \caption{some caption..}
\label{fig:short}
\end{figure*}
```

but it turned out figure-star only displays it's figure at the top of *next* page,
and when I just use figure like `\begin{figure}[htb]`, it's only located one of those two columns.

Does anyone know how to put a long figure between my title+name and body context?
Thanks.

Comment: (La)TeX-related questions are better suited on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com). I've flagged this for migration.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention anything about inserting a date in your title. So, why not use the date to store your image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe
\title{My Title}
\author{A.\ Uthor}
\date{\includegraphics[height=2in]{example-image}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

The [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) provides the example image (via [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)) and dummy text (via [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum)).